# ECMAScript 6 budget calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator, ecmascript-6

I never get to use ECMA6 in production/work, so I am hoping you all can help me write better code by reviewing my finished sample:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    class BudgCalc {

        constructor(personFullName, yearlyAfterTaxIncome) {

            this.name = personFullName;

            this.income = this.dollarsToCents(yearlyAfterTaxIncome);

            this.initialAfterTaxIncome = this.income;

            this.expenses = {
                daily: [],
                weekly: [],
                monthly: [],
                yearly: []
            }

            // To be calculated at runtime
            this.incomeBreakdown = {
                _startingIncome: this.centsToDollars(this.initialAfterTaxIncome), // _ is so its at the top of the object in the console only not because its private:)
                daily: 0,
                weekly: 0,
                monthly: 0,
                yearly: 0
            }

            //  Constants storing occurances per year
            this.dateData = {
                DAILY: 365,
                WEEKLY: 52,
                MONTHLY: 12,
                YEARLY: 1
            }

            this.setAmountsAvailableByTimePeriod();

            return this;
        }

        // dollars string to cents int
        dollarsToCents(curString) {
            var dolCentArr = curString.replace('$', '').replace(',', '').split('.'),
                dollarToCent = dolCentArr[0] * 100,
                origCents = dolCentArr[1] || 0, // For exact dollar amounts
                cents;

            if (origCents.length > 2) origCents = [origCents[0], origCents[1]]; // Truncate anything larger than .00

            cents = (parseInt(dollarToCent) + parseInt(origCents)); // Avoid type coersion here!

            return Math.round(cents);
        }

        // Turns dollars int to formatted USD currency string
        centsToDollars(centsInt) {
            var centsStr = `$${(parseInt(centsInt) / 100)}`,
                formattedUSMoneyArr = centsStr.split('.'),
                centsMember = formattedUSMoneyArr[1] || [],
                result;
            if (!centsMember.length) return centsStr + '.00'; // Add back in string format when js truncates a whole number (trailing .00's)
            else switch (true) {
                case centsMember.length === 1:
                    return centsStr + '0';
                    break; // .0+0
                case centsMember.length === 2:
                    return centsStr;
                    break; // Ok format here just return
                case centsMember.length > 2:
                    return formattedUSMoneyArr[0] + '.' + centsMember[0] + centsMember[1];
                    break; // Truncate larger than 99 cents 
            }
        }

        // Sets up the amounts available in time period
        setAmountsAvailableByTimePeriod() {
            this.incomeBreakdown.daily = this.centsToDollars(this.income / this.dateData.DAILY);
            this.incomeBreakdown.weekly = this.centsToDollars(this.income / this.dateData.WEEKLY);
            this.incomeBreakdown.monthly = this.centsToDollars(this.income / this.dateData.MONTHLY);
            this.incomeBreakdown.yearly = this.centsToDollars(this.income);
            return this;
        }

        setNewExpense(name, recurance, amount) {
            var bill = {},
                rate = this.dateData[recurance.toUpperCase()],
                matchingRecord = this.expenses[recurance];

            amount = this.dollarsToCents(amount);

            if (this.incomeBreakdown[recurance] && rate && matchingRecord) {
                this.income = Math.round(this.income - (amount * rate));
                bill[name] = this.centsToDollars(amount);
                matchingRecord.push(bill);
                this.setAmountsAvailableByTimePeriod();
            }

        }

        getFullReport() {
            return {
                expenses: this.expenses,
                budget: this.incomeBreakdown
            }
        }
    }

    class RenderUI extends BudgCalc {
        addExpense(nameStr, recuranceStr, amountStr) {
            // UI stuff in here, just leaving focus on the logic for now
            this.setNewExpense(nameStr, recuranceStr, amountStr);
        }
    }

    var app = new RenderUI('John Doe', (6450 * 24).toString() + '.00');

    app.addExpense('health insurance', 'monthly', '$200.00');
    app.addExpense('dining', 'daily', '$20.00');
    app.addExpense('car payment', 'monthly', '$300.00');
    app.addExpense('car insurance payment', 'monthly', '$300.23');
    app.addExpense('rent', 'monthly', '$1650.00');
    app.addExpense('cable', 'monthly', '175.00');
    app.addExpense('food', 'monthly', '$800.00');
    app.addExpense('gasoline', 'monthly', '$400.00233');
    app.addExpense('electric', 'monthly', '$110.00');
    app.addExpense('maggies phone', 'monthly', '$120.00');
    app.addExpense('savings', 'monthly', '$820.00');

    console.log({
        incomeReport: app.getFullReport()
    });

})();
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/zqKRYd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good but some suggestions are:

### Use `let`

If you're going to use ES6, you should probably use `let`. `let` generally helps avoid problems with scoping. Try to also use `const` for constants.

### Use `static`

If your function is not referencing `this` you should probably use `static`.

```
dollarsToCents(curString) {
```

to...

```
static dollarsToCents(curString) {
```

this may mean you'll have to change parts of your code but it allows access to these functions without having to go through `prototype` or create an instance of the class.

### Try to make conditionals clear at first glance

When I see:

```
!centsMember.length
```

It takes me a moment to figure out what this means. Rewriting this makes this a lot more clear:

```
centsMember.length === 0
```

### Use a radix on `parseInt`!

You're using `parseInt` without a radix. On some browsers, sometimes the browser will assume the wrong base which will cause problems, instead use:

```
parseInt(n, 10)
```

if your "stringified" number is guaranteed to be an integer, you can use any of the following:

```
Number(n)
+n
```

### Try to simplify code

When I first saw this, it took me a moment to see you're trying to get the first to digits.

```
if (origCents.length > 2) origCents = [origCents[0], origCents[1]]
```

Also, note this returns an array which you are passing into `parseInt` which will cause problems. Instead try something like:

```
origCents = origCents.substr(0, 2);
```

### Try to use regex more

Right here you have a couple of regexes:

```
.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
```

instead you could simplify this to:

```
.replace(/[$,]/g, '');
```

this will also be **g**lobal and will remove all occurrences.

### String templates

You're using string templates which is awesome but you can still make some more things string templates:

```
(6450 * 24).toString() + '.00'
```

can become...

```
`${6450 * 24}.00`
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. Just wondering, do you know if using let and const can also help performance?

Comment: @AlphaG33k The JavaScript engine will be able to optimize better when you're using `let` and `const` where applicable. While you may not notice a very significant speed boost, the engine _will_ be optimizing.

Comment: Moreover on the `parseInt` point, you could use `Number` instead, which doesn't require a radix and is more clearer IMO

Comment: @Quill true but Number does not ensure an integer

Comment: `Number` is an inherited `integer`, they are, for all intensive purposes, identical.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to make of this one so far. Should I use Number().. or parseInt(n, 10); ?

Comment: @AlphaG33k I'd use parseInt as it's more idiomatic imo but both are good practice

Comment: great coverage!

Answer (score 2):

Also, you should use [**Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

For eg:

```
centsToDollars(centsInt) {
  ...
}
```

would look something like:

```
centsToDollars = (centsInt) => {
  ...
}
```

As a side note, if you have a function with a single return value like:

```
centsToDollars(centsInt) {
  return (centsInt);
}
```

you could write that as:

```
centsToDollars = centsInt => centsInt
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yes thank you, I didn't think of this feature!

Comment: Should be noted that arrow functions in class definitions is an experimental ES7 feature - not a feature of ES6. You can't do this without a transpiler (Babel) and the appropriate configurations.

Comment: May I suggest improving your answer by explaining the difference of arrow functions (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target and are always anonymous.)

Comment: @SethMcClaine I've already attached the link in my answer and from there you will be able to know about arrow functions in details. But, anyways, thanks for the suggestion :)